# Is there a way to create polygon target areas in Ruby on Rails with a HTML file?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, polygon

So I'm trying to make an interactive map of New Jersey that makes it possible to click on a county in the state and it will take you to a different page. The file works fine in plain HTML with the county's being able to be clicked on and linked to separate pages. Trying to use it on ruby on rails does not work. It just displays the picture itself and there is no interaction available.

```
<%=image_tag("Map.jpg", :alt=>"#image-map")%>
<map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="Cape May County" title="Cape May County" href="https://www.capemaycountyherald.com/news/crime/" coords="172,863,196,861,226,838,225,827,228,817,240,799,249,784,257,766,261,760,273,751,278,743,274,735,252,741,240,739,228,735,207,733,199,732,195,744" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Cumberland County" title="Cumberland County" href="" coords="49,692,52,708,55,715,59,724,68,716,75,729,81,738,91,734,96,744,103,745,107,750,113,757,121,766,127,770,136,765,147,765,158,765,170,772,179,771,161,773,178,760,186,753,189,738,193,729,197,711,197,697,192,687,181,677,148,646,140,682,80,663,136,680,98,650" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Atlantic County" title="Atlantic County" href="" coords="179,669,188,679,196,685,200,695,201,715,212,731,237,735,260,735,270,734,280,733,287,731,299,725,311,721,321,715,328,708,334,699,342,685,345,679,346,670,232,590,173,654" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Ocean County" title="Ocean County" href="" coords="290,466,293,473,300,493,303,505,310,517,318,535,323,548,327,566,328,577,330,601,330,614,327,647,329,655,349,656,359,652,367,647,379,632,381,622,386,609,390,601,394,593,398,583,407,564,410,552,410,537,409,522,409,508,413,481,415,466,423,457,296,453,312,444,319,437,329,432,336,429,344,429,358,432,367,451,395,452,403,453,302,457" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Burlington County" title="Burlington County" href="" coords="253,438,271,449,276,462,282,476,289,498,302,531,321,567,325,589,324,607,323,625,310,639,290,627,282,616,278,612,266,605,239,590,231,584,225,577,219,563,195,554,187,542,182,528,173,518,169,509,162,500,154,488" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Salem County" title="Salem County" href="" coords="49,570,36,579,32,588,29,597,22,612,15,621,27,635,17,677,44,695,78,661,93,648,98,641,121,662,135,666,138,660,138,651,141,645,141,638,74,604,64,589,53,577" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Gloucester County" title="Gloucester County" href="" coords="51,559,59,571,65,582,71,591,100,606,113,609,124,616,134,624,146,638,165,654,190,633,179,604,135,561,114,534,77,547,68,549" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Monmouth County" title="Monmouth County" href="" coords="438,347,436,358,438,369,438,383,430,410,427,420,422,445,414,450,409,444,400,438,392,448,371,443,362,427,345,425,311,435,284,455,273,427,321,390,366,352,376,339,409,334" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Sussex County" title="Sussex County" href="" coords="246,10,268,24,284,38,305,47,329,59,319,72,311,76,306,91,296,99,284,115,273,128,250,159,243,163,225,162,221,155,202,138,194,123,182,109,172,102,209,40" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Bergen County" title="Bergen County" href="" coords="391,97,403,108,412,111,426,116,439,124,462,144,456,157,448,179,436,204,406,205,390,139,366,125,372,93" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Passaic County" title="Passaic County" href="" coords="363,133,359,144,360,157,366,169,396,190,386,146,327,126,303,109,335,67,352,76,360,80,368,89" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Mercer County" title="Mercer County" href="" coords="187,372,197,373,208,399,221,406,232,420,243,422,254,423,261,433,277,418,298,405,300,396,273,389,258,356,244,366,229,346,211,357" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Hunterdon County" title="Hunterdon County" href="" coords="120,277,144,261,165,243,180,231,189,223,201,222,218,230,231,238,235,269,235,292,224,304,213,309,221,329,218,339,187,366,149,334,143,288,115,284" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Camden County" title="Camden County" href="" coords="128,511,132,541,143,555,153,568,159,577,168,584,178,593,189,606,196,622,230,585,212,570,186,568,183,559,178,539,168,517,152,499" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Warren County" title="Warren County" href="" coords="130,139,141,159,145,165,154,177,154,188,142,190,145,202,114,219,118,237,113,255,117,261,133,260,146,247,171,236,177,219,181,209,189,207,199,200,207,188,220,166,205,152,207,150,199,139,187,133,183,124,170,109,147,129" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Morris County" title="Morris County" href="" coords="206,199,212,195,218,183,221,174,229,161,237,162,254,167,264,163,265,149,273,141,273,134,282,126,297,113,318,127,327,129,344,135,354,148,348,155,354,166,346,166,341,189,329,210,326,223,324,234,293,254,296,214,237,232,201,212" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Union County" title="Union County" href="" coords="326,273,355,277,378,272,391,248,367,239,356,237,332,233,313,250" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Middlesex County" title="Middlesex County" href="" coords="279,343,308,324,316,313,307,300,299,287,321,283,344,279,359,285,372,283,363,291,363,307,365,331,364,344,342,369,312,397,268,366" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Hudson County" title="Hudson County" href="" coords="397,255,403,239,392,224,396,219,423,204,435,209,425,234,407,258" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Somerset County" title="Somerset County" href="" coords="245,290,237,297,226,306,223,320,238,353,267,353,282,334,289,325,306,317,293,302,292,280,318,263,284,256,287,238,277,226,258,230,242,234,239,259,241,274" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="Essex County" title="Essex County" href="" coords="336,209,351,174,372,180,394,199,383,208,396,242,345,232,337,220" shape="poly">
</map>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Tried to remove the line : <map name="image-map"> , that did not change the issue fyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `:alt` to `:usemap` in your ERB code